# Generating a recursive descent parser for grammar having Kleene star

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, compilers, parsers, left-recursion

From what I have been taught, I cannot use left-recursive, nondeterministic, or ambiguous grammars in recursive descent parsers. So, here is the grammar:

\begin{align}
&E \to E+T \mid T \\
&T \to T\cdot F \mid F \\
&F \to F^* \mid a \mid b
\end{align}

I actually changed this to:

\begin{align}
&E \to TE' \\
&T \to +TE' \mid \epsilon \\
&T \to F\cdot T' \\
&T \to \cdot FT' \mid \epsilon \\
&F \to aF' \mid bF' \\
&F' \to ^*F' \mid \epsilon
\end{align}

This is done using the left-recursion elimination formula.

But then I have a doubt about whether it is correct or not, because the last $F$ transition cannot now generate $abb$, which it was able to generate. And if it is still able to do that, I would love to know, how?

Another transition that I tried for $F$ was:

\begin{align}
&F \to G^* \mid G \\
&G \to a \mid b
\end{align}

This was done to remove the left recursion without using any formula.

But then I realized that it made the last transition nondeterministic.

Then I tried changing it by using the left-recursion elimination formula on $F \to G^* \mid G$, making it:

\begin{align}
&F \to GF' \\
&F' \to ^*F' \mid \epsilon \\
&G \to a \mid b
\end{align}

And now I am all confused!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is a "standard" way to do left recursion elimination from Kleene star. But this is one obvious translation:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}F & \rightarrow & F^*\,|\, a \,| \,b \\ & & \Downarrow \\
F & \rightarrow & a F\,|\,b F\,|\,\epsilon\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 0):

```
here is code:
F -> W F | ϵ
W -> a|b|F
```